# WindowTester - Accessing file system (tree) item in a rcp client

Tags: tree, filesystems, swt, explorer, window-tester

I am wondering weather it is possible to reach tree elements in a Java RCP-Client which display a file system by using googles windowtester pro.

The tree (swt widget) shows my local file system (C:\Users...) much like the windows explorer (or TotalCommander, etc...).

Now I want to click the element

> C:\Users\me\Folder\file1.txt

After recording, windowtester tells me to do the folliwing:

> ui.click(new TreeItemLocator( "C:\/Users/me/Folder/file1.txt", new
> ViewLocator(
> de.zeb.control.fw.vfs.pl.rcp.client.views.FileBrowserView" ));

But executing this code I get the error:

> No tree items found for 'C:/Users' - wait then try again."

I also tried:

> "C:/Users/me/Folder/file1.txt"
>
> "\C:\/Users/me/Folder/file1.txt"
>
> "C:\\/Users\/me\/Folder\/file1.txt"

And various combinations, none of which seem to work.

Does anyone have an idea here?

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately escaping slashes is still a pain in WindowTester.

You have to look very carefully at the error message:

`No tree items found for 'C:/Users' - wait then try again."`

Compare this with the string given in the TreeItemLocator:

`"C:\/Users/me/Folder/file1.txt"`

Escaping the first slash obviously worked, but not the second one.
So every forward slash needs to be prefixed with a backward slash.
The correct string should then be:

`"C:\/Users\/me\/Folder\/file1.txt"`